# Unsure how to tensorize / vectorize this Image Kernel

Tags: python, c++, numpy, vectorization

I have the following operation that I am doing in C++ on a [3, H, W] tensor which stores an organized pointcloud:

```
  // Iterate on image / cloud
  for (auto yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
    for (auto xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {

      const float bad_point = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
      const int index = yy * width + xx;
      const float px = org_cloud_x_ptr[index];
      const float py = org_cloud_y_ptr[index];
      const float pz = org_cloud_z_ptr[index];

      if (std::isnan(px) || pz == 0) {
        normal_x_ptr[index] = bad_point;
        normal_y_ptr[index] = bad_point;
        normal_z_ptr[index] = bad_point;
        continue;
      }

      float matA0 = 0.0f;
      float matA1 = 0.0f;
      float matA3 = 0.0f;
      float vecb0 = 0.0f;
      float vecb1 = 0.0f;

      // Iterate neighbors
      for (auto v = yy - search_size; v <= yy + search_size; v += step_size) {
        for (auto u = xx - search_size; u <= xx + search_size; u += step_size) {

          if (u < 0 || u >= width || v < 0 || v >= height)
            continue;

          const int index2 = v * width + u;

          const float qx = org_cloud_x_ptr[index2];
          const float qy = org_cloud_y_ptr[index2];
          const float qz = org_cloud_z_ptr[index2];

          if (std::isnan(qx) || qz == 0)
            continue;

          const float dz = qz - pz;
          const float dx = qx - px;
          const float dy = qy - py;

          matA0 += dx * dx;
          matA1 += dx * dy;
          matA3 += dy * dy;
          vecb0 += dx * dz;
          vecb1 += dy * dz;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the output involves 5 tensors (matA0, matA1, matA3, vecb0, vecb1) of size [H,W] each. Right now, this is extremely slow (Takes 50ms on my CPU). As you can see, i am iterating through each point in the image/organized ptcloud, and i am then doing a kernel search, to compute 8 (neighbouring points) derivatives. I am then summing them in the following way in the code above.

Is there any way i can do this in a tensorized manner with numpy/torchlib etc. The solution I have now is as follows:

[image]

I run 8 of those kernels above per X/Y/Z channel to get me these derivatives, for a total of 24 outputs. I then sum them appropriately. This of course is a ton of memory and inefficient. Is there any other way?

Comment: Vectorization is not easy here, mainly because of the conditionals. Are they often true? What is the input size in practice? What is your target hardware?

Comment: I can remove the conditionals. They are mostly nan checks, i can ignore them. Input size is an 800x600 image. target hardware is a modern i9 cpu, code is compiled in release mode

Comment: I think Numpy will not help much compared to a C++ code. The problem with Numpy is that temporary arrays will make the resulting code either slow (because of allocations, internal checks, CPython calls, etc.) or use too much memory resulting in a suboptimal code (since the computation will not be performed in CPU caches). Numba may help in this case but it is less flexible than your C++ code. I think the C++ code can be optimized using vectorization and parallelization. Do you really want to use Python?

Comment: How big is `search_size`? What happens with `matA0`,...,`vecb1`? How likely is `std::isnan(px) || pz == 0`? Please post an actual [mre]!